# i need an interface to have accept concret type instead of interface in c#

Tags: c#, interface

the following interface has a concert type inside

```
public interface IHasCar{
    long IdCar {get;set;}
    Car car {get;set;}
}
```

I believe it should not, due to contract reasons so i tried
changing for an interface like this:

```
public interface IHasCar{
    long IdCar {get;set;}
    ICar car {get;set;}
}
```

then concrete class Car would implement ICar and any class what would
implement IHasCar could be something like this:

```
public foo : IHasCar{
    long IdCar {get;set;}
    Car car {get;set;}
}
```

it would have the concrete class Car which implements ICar, so foo would
implicitly implement IHasCar

unfortunately it does not work, i need a second atribute from concret class Car, what do i do without having concret class Car?

EDIT

one of the suggestions i got from friends was to write a function returning the value i want from Car, like this

```
public interface IHasCar{
    long IdCar {get;set;}
    long GetCarOwnerNumber(long IdCar) {get;set;}
}
```

this is not as good as using generics, but is it still acceptable? does it compromise interface principles or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

As the class implementing IHasCar does not fulfill the interface's contract, it will not compile, think about it, the interface accepts an ICar, ICar can be a Car or anything else, then when you try to set an ICar it's not guaranteed it will be a Car, so everything will break.

If you need the concrete class you can do something like this:

```
public foo : IHasCar
{
    long IdCar { get; set; }
    ICar car { get{ return mainCar; } set{ if(value is Car)mainCar = (Car)value; } }
    Car mainCar{ get; set; }
}
```

In this way you can use mainCar to access the Car and car to fulfill the interface.

Comment: Also, as a note, there's no problem in using a concrete class in our interface.

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to explicitly implement the `IHasCar.Car` property

Comment: `Car IHasCar.car { get{ return this.car; } set{ if(value is Car)this.car = value; } }` then the next line `Car car { get; set; }` This hides the interface version from intelisense and if you are working with a `IHasCar` object it forwards the request to the `Car car` property. A common example of this is when you have `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { this.GetEnumerator(); }  IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator<T>() { ...}`

Comment: there's no problem in using concret classes? i thought interface was meant for contract and abstraction only.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the use cases of [*generics*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

If `IHasCar` has an `ICar`, but you need to access `ICar` implementation members in an `IHasCar` implementation, then this is expressed as follows in C#:

```
public interface ICar
{
    // ICar members
}

public interface IHasCar<TCar>
       where TCar : class, ICar 
       // TCar must be a class and it must implement ICar
{
     TCar Car { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's implement an `ICar` and `IHasCar<TCar>`:

```
public class Car : ICar
{
}

public class Garage : IHasCar<Car>
{
     public Car Car { get; set; }

     public void DestroyCar()
     {
         // Now here your Garage implements IHasCar<Car>,
         // so Car property is typed as Car instead of IHasCar<Car>
         // and you'll be able to access Car members too!
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but i forgot to mention i didn't want to use generic in this particular case...

Comment: @scapegoat There's no way to elegantly solve your issue without generics. If you want through other route, you'll increase complexity and decrease run-time performance...........

Comment: i didn't want to use generics because every other class that uses the interface it would have to specify what the generics are... i do understand the power of generics, but i pretend to add three more objects to IHasCar and then it would have four generics clauses in my interface.. i am afraid the other classes that use IHasCar would be unreadable later.